# Replace string with matched expression

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

I have the following text in *multiple* files `Hello{Some Text}`, and I want to replace it with `Some Text`. Where `Some Text` might include balanced braces `{ }`. For example: `Hello{Some { other} Text}` should be replaced by `Some { other} Text`.

Is there an easy way to achieve this in `sed`, `awk`, `perl` or some other tool?

Comment: You have to choose perl. Try `Hello({((?:[^{}]*+|(?1))*)})` and replace with `\2`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/AIlUV5/1

Comment: Regex is notoriously bad at directly finding balanced delimiters without a hugely overcomplicated expression. Some alternatives are [Text::Balanced](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Balanced) or tokenizing your text with something like [Parser::MGC](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parser::MGC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to choose `perl` since it supports sub-routine calls. A recursive match on `{[^{}]*}` should occur continuously and should fail if an unbalanced brace is found. Below regex does the job:

```
Hello({((?:[^{}]*+|(?1))*)})
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/AIlUV5/1)

Note: it fails on facing with escaped braces.

Perl:

```
$ echo 'Hello{Some { other} Text}' | perl -pe 's~Hello({((?:[^{}]*+|(?1))*)})~$2~g'
Some { other} Text
```

Regex breakdown:

```
Hello # Match `Hello`
( # Start of 1st capturing group
    { # Match `{`
    ( # Start of 2nd capturing group
        (?: # Start of non-capturing group
            [^{}]*+ # Match anything but `{` or `}` possessively
            | # Or
            (?1) # Recurs first group
        )* # End of NCG, repeat as much as possible
    ) # End of 2nd CP
    } # Match `}`
) # End of 1st CP
```

Comment: Is the possessive quantifier really needed here (on left part of the alternation)? It works well without, maybe the interest is elsewhere, for some kind of optimisation maybe?

Comment: @PJProudhon It's needed to avoid catastrophic backtracking on failures. See what happens without it https://regex101.com/r/AIlUV5/2

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain what you mean by "it fails on facing with escaped braces."?

Comment: @Tohiko Sure. It means `Hello{Some{ \{Text}}` will not produce a match. This regex doesn't match escaped braces.